# Can I set up an internal endpoint to load-balanced worker roles in another deployment in another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Over time I'm planning to have a suite of applications (web roles) each executing in their own deployments within their own subscriptions under an Azure enterprise account.  I'd like these applications to call a common HTTP-based API, which I'd hoped would live in its own deployment/ subscription and be load balanced.

How would I set up endpoint communication so that the suite of apps have the appropriate input endpoints exposed to the internet, yet the back-end API services would not be exposed to the internet but instead just to the applications?   An internal endpoint that allows cross-deployment communication?

I may be misunderstanding but it seems like the endpoint and network traffic stuff controls only intra-deployment communication -- can I reach across deployments with an internal endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Deployments are network-isolated from each other, so you'd need to expose an input endpoint, which means it would be accessible via the internet, or use some other means of communication, like Service Bus.

Note that if you expose an input endpoint, you could always use some sort of authentication, like X509 certs, to lock down access.